# Charging a 9volt battery with a jst or dc plug

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, charging

I just want to make sure what I am thinking about doing will work and I will not cause a fire in the process. I would like to connect  a 9v rechargeable battery to a small dc motor in a plastic model (this part I can do). I wanted to know if I can solder a jst connector or a 2.1x5.5 mm  dc plug to the two leads on the battery while connected to the motor (motor off). I wanted to know if I could solder the complementary part of the dc plug to the appropriate charger.  The reason for this is I will not be able to get to the battery easily and wish to charge it so it is not one time use. If anybody has a simpler way or idea it would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you soldering to a battery holder's terminals, or directly to the battery terminals?

Comment: I was going to solder it to the holders terminals and make it like a Y. One part to the motor and one part to the jst or dc plug to the charger.

Answer (score 1):

Your plan should be fine provided you use a hot iron and work quickly -- the battery holder should provide enough heatsinking to keep the battery from being too unhappy under those circumstances.  Feel free to remove the battery during the soldering process if you feel that'd be safer, though.

Comment: Thanks so much. I will definitely solder it all up before the battery is attached. Glad to hear it should work.